# Google tag manager - is it possible to push in dataLayer with custom clientID

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, enhanced-ecommerce

I'm trying to implement UA Enhanced Ecommerce using Google Tag Manager(Data Layer) for two person interactions(Buyer - Seller).

As I understand when `dataLayer.push()` happens and data goes to GA - [clientID](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6205850?hl=en#clientid-userid) is unique user identifier.

All interaction steps are going on Buyer side, except Responded step.

Is it possible to make `dataLayer.push()` with Buyer clientID(what I save in database) on Responded step, because now I see funnel gap in Google Analytics Checkout Behavior report?
[image]

Comment: There's a lack of information about what you're trying to accomplish. What's a two-person interaction? What's a "first person" client ID? What problem are you trying to tackle? What code have you tried, and what were the error messages? Remember this is StackOverflow where questions are code-centric.

Comment: @nyuen Hope now question is more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for me was to use [Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/) and send wanted data from backend.